# Which commercial jet aircraft have the option to install ACT (Additional Center Tank)?

Tags: fuel-tanks

Which commercial jet aircraft have the option to install ACT (Additional Center Tank)? I think A321 has this option but I am not sure which other commercial jets have this option or this can be done with almost any plane?

Comment: 'Plane' covers a LOT of aircraft, ranging from home built experimental craft up to military experimental craft. Surely it's clear that not ALL aircraft will have this option and ability?

Comment: modified it...   i was mainly interested for commercial jets..  i know many small business aircrafts have this option.

Comment: The boeing 737 does. They add a fuel tank in the center of the fuselage and when there is a fuel tank is added it is called an ER(extended range). Boeing 737-900ER is the most common aircraft I have heard of with an ACT

Comment: Is it a fixed sized ACT or can have different versions? Any idea on that?

Comment: Since this question has two downvotes, I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of a non permanent installation almost any aircraft can be plumbed to accept a [Ferry Tank(s)](http://www.turtlepac.com/photo-gallery/aircraft-ferry-tanks.html) this is typically done for smaller aircraft to transport them over open water distances they can not otherwise cross. As far as I know this is not really done in commercial operations but you can add tanks.

[This article](http://aviationweek.com/commercial-aviation/airbus-launches-long-range-a321neo-version) seems to confirm the center tank on the A321.

If you are asking about a tank that can be added and removed quickly I do not know of any but from a regulatory standpoint doing so would require separate weight and balances to be prepared for both cases.